# Jeweler adds circular dependency to my gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

Gem's(gemfoo) jeweler declaration in Rakefile looks like that:

```
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
  #truncated
  gem.add_runtime_dependency 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.1'
  gem.add_development_dependency 'jeweler'
end
```

The problem is that it generates the following dependencies in the gemfoo.gemspec file:

`s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<gemfoo>, [">= 0"])
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<nokogiri>, ["~> 1.4.1"])
s.add_development_dependency(%q<jeweler>, [">= 0"])`

Which won't stop you from releasing your rubygem but won't allow you to install it:

```
gem install gemfoo
ERROR:  Error installing gemfoo:
    gemfoo requires gemfoo (>= 0)
```

How can I fix that?

---

jeweler 1.6.0

Comment: Seeing the truncated part from your `Rakefile` might help. Seems strange that the gem itself is a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is broken in your Rakefile. Jeweler 1.6.0

```
require 'jeweler'
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
  gem.name = "gemfoo"
  gem.summary = %Q{TODO: one-line summary of your gem}
  gem.description = %Q{TODO: longer description of your gem}
  gem.email = "john@example.com"
  gem.homepage = "http://www.google.com/"
  gem.authors = ["John Doe"]
  gem.add_runtime_dependency 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.1'
  gem.add_development_dependency 'jeweler'
end
Jeweler::RubygemsDotOrgTasks.new
```

`rake gemspec` - the generated gemspec file doesn't have the artifact you're describing.